# My first home network Cat 5e, fiber 1 gig internet

Tags: data-wiring, low-voltage, ethernet, wifi

Thank you for taking the time and reading this, I hope you can give me a green light on my plans here!?

I am getting fiber internet and wanted to set it up the following way. Please let me know if that works and feel free to suggest a different way.

Fiber comes to the detached garage.
cat 5e from the box to a 5 way 1gig switch (unmanaged) 
  port 1 - to the house 
  port 2 - (already have) apple airport express with audio for sound in the garage
  port 3,4,5, for potential IP cam/NVR

In the house
cat 5e from the garage to the router/wifi from Xfinity C3000A - should do a great job!?
to another 8way switch (unmanaged) 
  port 1 - to the apple tv
  port 2 - mango console
  port 3 - upstairs with Time capsule/wifi if needed
  port 4-8 open for IP Cameras/other rooms if needed

Questions:

1. if I have the cable from the street to the garage with switch and then in the house much later the router/wifi that should still work, right? Since ethernet goes both ways??
2. In general, please let me know a better way if you got one.

Thank you so much in advance. I'll start working on this tomorrow.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a shopping question and is off topic. If you take the tour you will understand how stack exchange DIY works.

Comment: Thank you Ed! My main question is if the series of: fiber - box -  switch - 5e - wifi/router - switch - tv,computers,...   works  or do I have to go from the fiber to the house with the router/wifi and back out to the garage. What switch to use was referring to managed/unmanaged. I think that is a question within the limits?

Comment: BTW: can you replace the router in the house with a simple AP and a switch? That'd be less error-prone to set up....

Comment: Thank you so much! I know for most of you this sounds like a question of: Do I put a trailer in front or behind a car, right!

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing your question to remove the shopping portion so it may remain open.

Comment: Does your fiber bridge provide its own routing/NAT/... functions, or does it need an external/separate router to provide those for it?

Answer (score 4):

Although it is true that Ethernet is bidirectional, it is still necessary that the packets from your fiber bridge reach the router before going to your other devices (and visa versa). This is because one of the functions of your router is to take the devices on your network and represent them to the outside Internet as a single device (actually multiple IP addresses as a single) using a protocol called [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). Your network provider is probably expecting to see a single device (IP address) only and the router “fools” it.

Now because a single physical network can carry multiple logical networks through IP subnetting, it is possible to use a single cable between your garage and house and still run the packets to the router first. However, since this requires proper configuration of your local network and could require reconfiguration in the future if your provider’s configuration changes, I don’t recommend it to someone without knowledge of networking. It also requires an addition unmanaged switch at the router.

Assuming you need the router in the house, due to WiFi range limitations, I’d suggest that you run two CAT5E (or better) cables between the garage and house: one from your fiber bridge to the router WAN/Internet port and one back from a router LAN port to the switch.